# How do you undeploy a BizTalk ESB itinerary?

Tags: biztalk, esb-toolkit-2.1

How do you undeploy a BizTalk 2010 ESB 2.1 itinerary?

I can see the `EsbImportUtil.exe` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk ESB Toolkit 2.1\Bin`,  but there isn't a corresponding *undeploy* tool.

Or is it a brute force `DELETE FROM dbo.Itinerary WHERE XXX` !!

Comment: I still think you should take a look at the BizTalk Deployment Framework.  All of the deployment questions you have asked in the past week are handled rather nicely by the BTDF (http://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @BenRunchey Ben, I'm working through creating a BTDF package, but there are some things it doesn't cover. Undeploying an ESB itinerary is one of them, as are a number of my other questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no executable within ESB folder to undeploy your Itinerary, basically EsbImportUtil utility was created to deploy your Itinerary on a server doesn't run Visual studio, and because ESB is just a toolkit, they have not thought about undeploying

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit exe provided for undeploying the itineraries.
However, you could use a post deployment SQL script that deletes the Itinerary from the database.